# How do I prevent my screen from freezing after booting successfully on Acer Aspire 5520G laptop?

Tags: screen, freeze, acer, aspire

I own an Acer Aspire 5520G and just installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Win7 Ultimate. Both are 32bit. I am able to boot into either via GRUB. However, I am facing two  problems:

1. The computer often freezes after booting up successsfuly into Ubuntu. The desktop appears and I can move the mouse, but the buttons on the mouse will not work. Sometimes I can't even move the mouse.
2. The wireless adapter is detected, but I am unable to add a wireless network and put in a passkey.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!